# \cite within parenthesis without using \parencite in BibLaTeX, to get "Author1 & Author2" (APA)

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa6, apa7

I'm using BibLaTeX and the APA-7 bibliography style.

I normally use `\textcite{}` and `\parencite{}` to get respectively "Doe and Adams (2010)" or "(Doe & Adams, 2010)" in APA style. As you can see, APA mandates "&" within the parenthesis and "and" outside of it.

Now, I occasionally need to include a reference within a long, existing parenthesis, such as

> ... (between M = 3.49, SD = 0.7 for low-intermediate learners and M = 6.23, SD = 1.15 for advanced learners in Kormos & Denes, 2004).

which I would typically try to get using `\cite{}`

```
(between M = 3.49, SD = 0.7 for low-intermediate learners and M = 6.23, SD = 1.15
for advanced learners in \cite{KormosDenes2004}).
```

The problem is that this results in BibLaTeX producing "Kormos and Denes" rather than "Kormos & Denes" within the parenthesis.

Is there a solution?

(Considering the length of the parenthesis, I prefer not to put everything in the optional argument before `parencite`, because `\parencite[between M = 3.49, SD = 0.7 for low-intermediate learners and M = 6.23, SD = 1.15 for advanced learners in][]{KormosDenes2004}` in not very readable and I sometimes need to include multiple references at different places of the same parenthesis.)

Full reproducible code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{KormosDenes2004,
  title = {Exploring Measures and Perceptions of Fluency in the Speech of Second Language Learners},
  author = {Kormos, Judit and Dénes, Mariann},
  date = {2004}, journaltitle = {System}, volume = {32}, number = {2}, pages = {145--164}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{apa7}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\author{Jane Doe}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Mean length of runs (between M = 3.49, SD = 0.7 for low-intermediate learners and M = 6.23, SD = 1.15
for advanced learners in \cite{KormosDenes2004}).

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `biblatex-apa` you can use `\nptextcite` to obtain the parenthetical citation style without parentheses for use in manually typeset parentheses.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
(between $\mathrm{M} = 3.49$, $\mathrm{SD} = 0.7$ for low-intermediate learners
and $\mathrm{M} = 6.23$, $\mathrm{SD} = 1.15$ for advanced learners
in \nptextcite{sigfridsson}).

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (between M = 3.49, SD = 0.7 for low-intermediate learners and M = 6.23, SD = 1.15 for advanced learners in Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998).]